# Can't seem to iterate over a sorted dictionary where the keys are number strings. How do you sort a dictionary to iterate?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have this dictionary (dic) where the keys are strings, but the strings are actually just numbers.

I can't find a way to iterate over the sorted string (since sorting the dictionary will not sort numerically)

```
for j in sorted([int(k) for k in dic.iteritems()]):
    print dic[str(j)] #converting the integer back into a string for the key
```

it gives me

> KeyError

Intuitively this should work, but I just dont get why it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dict.iteritems()` returns 2-tuples, which cannot be converted into ints.

```
for j in sorted(dic, key=int):
    print dic[j]
```

Comment: Very true, but that would result in a `TypeError`, not a `KeyError`.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Assuming what the asker wrote is accurate.

Comment: Omg. This is so frustrating to know. Just why something would do this. I didnt even know you could do sorted(dic, key=int)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using `key=int` you could also slightly modify your existing comprehension:

```
for _, value in sorted((int(key), dic[key]) for key in dic):
     print(value)
```

it's not as nice but it's an alternative if you want to unpack not only your keys but also your values.

---

With iteritems you need an additional unpacking in the comprehension:

```
for _, value in sorted((int(key), value) for key, value in dic.iteritems()):
     print(value)
```